# Running application in background and catching incoming and outgoing messages

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am working on one app which I want to run in background and it should handle the event when any sms gets received and my application should receive that sms even if this application is closed.  Till now my application is getting sms only when it is opened . I want it to catch all messages received even it is closed. Similarly I want this for sent messages .

Could anyone please tell me how should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only way to do that would be with a long running headless application. You will need a special signing key and it won't be available to users until 10.2.1 is released.

Also, BlackBerry is far more protective of user privacy than some other platforms. You will likely only get permission to run such an application headless if you have a very good reason to access all incomming and outgoing SMS.

Comment: Thanks Richard . I have registered for getting permission for long running headless app last last week . I came to know that after requesting , BlackBerry will reply me for this request but I didn't get any reply from BlackBerry portal. What shall I do now?

Comment: I understand that it can take some time to get a reply. They have to evaluate your request to see if the proposed application is in line with their goals for the system. You will just have to wait.